# Remove duplicate of a list via list matching in Python

Tags: python

I have chosen a slightly different procedure to remove duplicates of a list. I want to keep a new list in parallel, in which each duplicate is added. Afterwards I check if the element is present in the "newly created list" in order to delete it.

The code looks like this:

```
# nums = [1,1,2] or [0,0,1,1,1,2,2,3,3,4]

t = []
nums_new = nums
for i in nums:
    if nums[i] not in t:
        t.append(nums[i])
    else:
        nums_new.remove(nums[i])
nums = nums_new
print(nums)
```

For the case when `nums = [1,1,2]` this works fine and returns `[1,2]`.

However, for `nums = [0,0,1,1,1,2,2,3,3,4]` this case does not seem to work as I get the following output: `[0, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4]`.

Why is this? Can someone explain me the steps?

Comment: `for i in nums` makes `i` an element of `nums`, not an index. so instead of `nums[i]` you should just use `i`

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki if i do so, i still get an incorrect list somehow...

Comment: please, edit your question with the updated code, the input list you are using and the result you are getting

Comment: Is there a motivation not to do `nums = list(set(nums))`? Note that removing elements from a list while iterating over is fraught with peril.

Comment: If only you hadn't chosen test cases where all the elements are valid indices, for instance `nums = ['1', '1', '2']`... (Doesn't what you want to do just leave you with two identical lists?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two issues with your code:

1. Since you are [iterating over a list](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html), `for i in nums`, `i` is your actual number, not the indexer, so you should just use `i` instead of `nums[i]`.
2. `nums_new = nums` will not actually make a copy of `nums`, but instead it will [make a second binding to the very same list](https://docs.python.org/3/library/copy.html).  So you should write `nums_new = nums.copy()` to avoid changing your original list while you iterate over it.

With those two changes your code works as you wish:

```py
nums = [0,0,1,1,1,2,2,3,3,4]

t = []
nums_new = nums.copy()
for i in nums:
    if i not in t:
        t.append(i)
    else:
        nums_new.remove(i)

nums = nums_new

print(nums)
```

Returns `[0,1,2,3,4]`.

Of course this is an academic exercise of some kind, but note that the Pythonic way to [remove duplicates from a list is](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7961363/removing-duplicates-in-lists):

- `list(dict.fromkeys(nums))` if you want to preserve the order, and
- `list(set(nums))` for a slightly faster method if you do not care about order.

Comment: i know this approach as well, but my usecase was such that i had to choose this approach. But I must have forgotten the `.copy()`. thanks for the explanation!